# Domain Name Routing on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, dns, domain, django

I am trying to route my domain name on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu Droplet. I was curious if there is a default location where I can go to route this or if it is not that simple. The server is running Django. Would the domain routing take place within the Django app or does it need to be configured from a different location on the server? In other words, when a user enters "gitship.com" into their browser, how do I route it to my Django app on the server? I have already add the domain on DigitalOcean. I just need to find the right place to add it on the droplet. When I enter gitship.com into my browser right now I get "This site can’t be reached
gitship.com’s server IP address could not be found."

Comment: when a user enters "gitship.com" into their browser, it goes to the django app on the server.

Comment: Start here https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/

Comment: I have already add the domain on DigitalOcean. I just need to find the right place to add it on the droplet.

Comment: When you do enter gitship.com in your browser, what happens, and what (error) message do you get? (Answer in your question please... you get the style :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that

> gitship.com’s server IP address could not be found

You haven't yet set up the DNS for the domain.

This is way out of scope here, but https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/ will help you in your way.

---

I see you've now set up www.gitship.com (which is a different host to gitship.com). But you've either a firewall on ports 80 and 443, or the Django web server isn't running.

Comment: I have already configured the DNS for the domain on DigitalOcean as NS records.

Comment: NS gitship.com  directs to ns1.digitalocean.com. 1800

Comment: NS gitship.com directs to ns2.digitalocean.com. 1800

Comment: NS gitship.com directs to ns3.digitalocean.com. 1800

Comment: Yes. But you haven't set up any A records, so you still haven't configured the DNS.

Comment: Ok. Just trying to understand this. Once I configure the A and NS records, it is just a matter of physically going into the server and adding the domain name to the server or Django app?

Comment: I fixed it but now I am getting "This site can’t be reached
www.gitship.com refused to connect.

Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall"

Comment: As of now, 2nd October, 19:10 UTC, there is still no DNS 'A' entry for gitship.com. (You can convert that time to your local timezone with `date --date 'TZ="UTC" 2018-10-02 19:10'`.) Ah. You've changed the goalpost:- you've set up www.gitship.com. That's different.

Comment: could we move to chat to solve this? Or should I try a different strategy?

Comment: Is there a way to check the firewall on 80 or 443 or a way to see if Django is running properly?